# Precisely determining the number of executions in a program

Tags: c++, math

Can someone help me determine how many times the statement will execute in the inner-most loop?

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        for(int k = j; k <= n; k++)
            //statement
```

I'm not really sure how to approach problems of this form, and I thought it would be a helpful exercise if someone could outline the thought process one may go through to tackle such a problem.  Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: Start with one loop, then two, then three. Look for a pattern

Comment: How many times does the outer loop execute? For each of those executions how many times does the next loop execute? And for each of *those* how many times does the inner loop execute? Think about it a little and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: @peter, this is not homework.

Comment: I don't see why people are voting to close this.  It seems a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Thank, it just looked like it might be,  such questions out of curiosity are rare.  The answer is in the answers and @oli provided most of the why

Answer (score 1):

So, the first loop (using `i`) iterates while the `i <= n` is true - which means that if `n >= 1`, it will iterate `n` times. Same for the `j` loop. So far we have `n * n` iterations.

The third `k` loop is a bit trickier, as it starts at `j`, so the first time, it will run from `1` to `n`, but next time it starts at 2, etc until `j == n`, where it only runs once. On average, that is `n/2` iterations.

So this makes `n * n * (n+1)/2` iterations in total.

Comment: That is almost correct, the correct answer is in my answer, it's n-1

Comment: @PeterWooster: Nope, it's (n+1)...

Comment: @oli That is correct, it should be n+1, but it is not n, I updated my answer.

Comment: I've also updated mine...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is n*n*(n+1)/2

Why is left as an exercise for the reader